# jitsi account "name" or "default identiy" sticks and cannot be removed

Tags: linux, voip, irc, sip, jitsi

how do I change or remove where it shows a "name" above `offline` to the right of the silhouette of the user and below the `files tools help` menu?

[image: jitsi]

I removed all accounts.  I'm only using Jitsi for SIP at the moment, but might use it for IRC -- again, there are no accounts.

Answer (score 0):

After fully exiting Jitsi, it was removed and changed to "me":

[image: jitsi me]

but, how do I change that text without exiting and restarting Jitsi?